# Arabic string: get actual Glyph (contextual shaping)

Tags: .net, string, arabic

I have an arabic String. For instance: رامات راحيل

In Arabic, the same letter has a different glyph according to the letter position.
So letter Lam is ل if Isolated or Initial, while is ﻟ if it's medial or final.

When I transform the original string (.NET) in a char array, all the chars are returned as Isolated.

Is it possible to have the actual glyphs?

I have to "translate" Arabic chars and send them to a device. So ل has code 128 (for instance) while ﻟ has code 129.
The translation table is custom.

It doesn't matter how I get the char, in all the cases they are returned as Isolated:

```
Dim a As String = "رامات راحيل"
Dim ar As Char() = a.ToCharArray

For Each c As Char In ar
    Console.WriteLine(c)
Next

For i As Integer = 0 To a.Length - 1
    Console.WriteLine(a.Substring(i, 1))
Next

For i As Integer = 0 To a.Length - 1
    Console.WriteLine(a.Chars(i))
Next
```

My understading is that the code is the same, but the shape is different.
See par. Contextual shaping http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688137.aspx

Comment: For a better understanding, why do you need to transform it into the char Array instead of keeping it as a string?

Comment: I have to "translate" Arabic chars and send them to a device. So ل has code 128 (for instance) while ﻟ has code 129.

Comment: How did you split into the Char array?

Comment: Did you try Encoding.GetBytes()?

Comment: I tried, but no result: the letter is the same, so even the code is the same. Just the glyph is different.

Comment: Have you tried inserting a non-printing (control) character in front of the character?

Comment: @Gusdor: why should I do it?

Comment: @Matte _"So letter Lam is ل if Isolated or Initial, while is ﻟ if it's medial or final."_ Attempt to make it medial or final with a non-spacing character.

Answer (score 0):

You loose the information about position when converting to a char array. Obvious all chars are isolated and therefore can be used anywhere. Interesting that for a writing it makes a difference here (learn something new everyday).

You have two options:

- Save another array for every char and save if the char was initial, alone, medial or final.
- Do the translation to the array by yourself. As you were able to input two different UTF-8 chars here on the website there must be a seperate UTF-8 char. So take a look at your string and build your own Char array creator who will understand when to take one or another.

Comment: My understading is that char is the same, just the glyph is different: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/goglobal/bb688137.aspx (see par. Contextual shaping)

Comment: Okay I see. This goes even further than I have known. Guess you will have to do something like the first option but not sure how you could handle that properly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is GetCharacterPlacement from GDI, ScriptShape from Uniscribe or GetGlyphs from DirectWrite's IDWriteTextAnalyzer that will do this.  Alternatively since these are not only glyphs but actually alternate characters as defined by the Unicode standard in the Arabic Presentation range, you could simply make your own translation table though taking care to ignore combining diacritical symbols when determining initial, final, medial or isolated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a full solution to this issue. It consists of a glyph definition file plus a cpp utility function to get the actual glyphs using char codes

please find more details and download the files [from here](https://arabicocr.wordpress.com/2015/07/01/working-with-arabic-glyphs/)

Answer (score -1):

You should consider

- reading the glyphs from the GSUB (Glyph Substitution) table of the TTF (True Type Font)
  (https://www.microsoft.com/typography/tt/tt_open/msdn/ttoch03.doc)
- try to make use of the ScriptGetFontAlternateGlyphs function of the
  Uniscribe API (Windows lib)
  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)